# How to show prompt for location permissions in WebView Android

Tags: android, reactjs, webview

I have a problem with my WebView in Android. I'm trying to show a website inside my app using a WebView, but my website asks for location permission. The problem is that when my WebView tries to open this site, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of
> undefined

This error occurs because I haven't accepted the prompt for location permission, and the prompt never shows up in my WebView."

This is the prompt:

[image]

And this is my code that I use to load the website inside of my webview:

```
    WebSettings settings = webViewClub.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webViewClub.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webViewClub.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webViewClub.clearCache(true);
    webViewClub.clearHistory();
    superProgressBar.setMax(100);
    webViewClub.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }else{
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            superLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            superLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    webViewClub.setWebChromeClient(new CustomChromeClient());
    webViewClub.loadUrl("https://app-con-permisos/");
```

And this is my custom method that extends from WebChromeClient:

```
public class CustomChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            Log.d("HIDDEO", "Ejemplo");
            //check for permissions or show your dialog etc
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            Log.d(TAG, "Estamos en el Webclient de chrome Club de descuentos");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            Log.d(TAG, "Estamos en el Webclient de chrome Club de descuentos");
        }

    }
```

I've tried using the function **onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt**, but it's not working. This function doesn't do anything.

Comment: Without html source we dont know what should happen.

Comment: @blackapps okay, so the problem could be the source in html? I don't have access to the code